# Riverpod is not updating UI widget on state change

Tags: flutter, riverpod

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _appProvider =
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AppProvider>((ref) => AppProvider());

  final _profileProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<ProfileProvider>((ref) {
    return ProfileProvider();
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    AppProvider appProvider = ref.watch(_appProvider);
    ProfileProvider profileManager = ref.watch(_profileProvider);
    print(appProvider.appLocale);
}
```

appProvider.dart

```
class AppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale? _appLocale = const Locale('en');

  Locale get appLocale => _appLocale ?? const Locale("en");

  static const supportedLanguage = [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('km', 'KH')];
    
      void changeLanguage(Locale type) async {
        _appLocale = type;

   notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image]

// when i log value of _appLocale here , I can see the update value based on the state change. but it does not re render UI widgeet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by declaring global provider, remove any deplicated provider, same name, in other files.